# Adding new classes to a logistic regression classifier without re-training

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, supervised-learning

Many real world classification problems have a ever-changing set of possible classes.

Let's say I have a training set where each training example belongs to one of three different classes `A`, `B` or `C`. Once I've trained a logistic regression classifier on such a set and I wish to add new examples with a new label `D` to it, is there a way to re-train the classifier without throwing away all of the information it's learned about classes `A`, `B` & `C`? In other words, do I have to re-train from scratch, or is there a smarter way of dealing with this situation?